# Load binary and name name to RadAsyncUpload from server side (OnLoad Event)

Tags: c#, telerik, server-side, radupload

I have a custom *.acsx control to show/edit RadGrid items. Each records has a binary file that was previously uploaded. But I'm having problem to load those binaries to the RadAsyncUpload.
Does anyone can help me to figure this out?

Comment: If they were previously uploaded, then why do you have to upload again with RadAsyncUpload?

Comment: I don't want to upload again, I want to show it on the edit form...

Comment: So you have a webForm and want to get the URL pathnames of the binary files that were uploaded.  So can't you just search the HTML data for the URLs?